# Form element access in unobtrusive ajax event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-ajax

I'd like to hook into a ajax callback for a specific form that's using unobtrusive ajax.
The ajax call is no problem with this standard form using unobtrusive ajax:

```
<form action="/xyz" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" id="someformid" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="bla" />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

My first approach was this:

```
var form = $("#someformid");
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, request, options) {
    // is not hitting here
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
This approach hits the handler, but not just for the desired form. But for all ajaxComplete events.

```
var form = $("#someformid");
form.submit(function (eevent) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, request, options) {
        // this hits ok. but not just for this form
    });
});
```

Next option would be to use the "data-ajax-success". but that doesn't seem to supply the form context.

So the question:
How do I hook up a ajaxComplete event for just one form exclusively.

Note:
**I'd like to avoid workarounds like matching the url or adding some unique id to the query.**

Thanks!

Comment: I would try giving the `<button>` and **id** and using that **id** as the selector for the `.ajaxComplete()`. Just a suggestion, don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `.ajaxComplete()` docs:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document. All ajaxComplete handlers are invoked, regardless of what
>   Ajax request was completed. If you must differentiate between the
>   requests, use the parameters passed to the handler. Each time an
>   ajaxComplete handler is executed, it is passed the event object, the
>   XMLHttpRequest object, and the settings object that was used in the
>   creation of the request. For example, you can restrict the callback to
>   only handling events dealing with a particular URL:

So, the way I read this is, if you know you'll be running a specific URL (your php processing script), then you can pass that URL in the settings to the `.ajaxComplete()` method.... (in your case, "/xyz")

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "/xyz" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
      xhr.responseHTML );
  }
});
```